# Why does instantiating a new object in each iteration of a for loop overwrite previous list entries?

Tags: c#, class, for-loop, .net-core

I'm trying to dynamically populate a list of objects as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
            List<MainObject> objects = new List<MainObject>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                objects.Add(new MainObject(item));
                foreach (MainObject o in objects)
                    Console.WriteLine(o.getString());
            }

        }
    }

class MainObject
{
    public MainObject() { }
    public MainObject(string theString) { nString = theString; cString = theString; }

    private static string nString { get; set; }
    private static string cString { get; set; }

        public string getString() { return nString; }
    }
}
```

I figure that since I'm using the "new" operator I'm instantiating a new object each loop, but it overwrites the previous entry every time.

It gives an output like the following:

```
item1
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
```

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? When you step through the program in the debugger where does it go awry?

Comment: I would actually expect the output to be `1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3` not `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3`. because each time you add an item, you are printing out each item in the list at that moment.

Comment: Please post the actual code. 1) `object` is a keyword and requires the `@` prefix to be used as an identifier. 2) `Object`, the static type of the would-be "`object`" range variable, does not have a `getValue` method. 3) As JamesFaix stated, the order doesn't look like it could be produced by that code. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: @madrefleciton I can't use the actual code due to it being confidential so I've changed all variable names to generic placeholders of "Object", "objects", and "stringList".

It's really bizarre to me as well as this is definitely not the ouput I am expecting whatsoever.

Comment: @JamesFaix that is what I would expect as well, but that's not what is happening. It's clear to me that the list is being overwritten with each repetition of the outer foreach loop.

Comment: @HABO I have done rubber ducky debugging quite a bit and I'm still left lost, which is why I've come here.

Comment: Changing the variable names is fine, but whatever you post still should be able to compile if you're going to claim that it gives you a certain output. In this case, to deliver a [mre], create a new project and use any variable name you want. Build and run, then copy/paste into your question. If someone tries to copy/paste to [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), it should compile, run, and show the same output.

Comment: If it *doesn't* show the same output as the original code, you already a basis for diagnosing the problem. You can compare the two implementations and see what the difference is. This is right up there with rubber-duck debugging among the tools programmers use to diagnose their problems.

Comment: And while it may be "clear" to you that the list is being overwritten, that's an unfounded logical leap. In fact, if `getValue` somehow returns `"Object" + objects.Count`, that would explain the output, but then it would also raise a lot of questions such as why the "`Object`" class has a reference to the `objects` variable. So what *does* `getValue` return? There simply isn't enough information to determine what's going on because you haven't posted a *reproducible* example.

Comment: Hey @madreflection thanks for all the input, I am rather new to debugging so I appreciate your help.

I recreated the code in a standalone program with new variables: that you can see in this pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/9y9kJ0zy

the output it gave me was the following:

item1
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3


This means that the behaviour is in fact a matter of overwriting

Comment: [Edit] your question with the new code. This is the correct thing to do on StackOverflow.

Comment: That is not the same as what you originally posted. The original code had nested loops. This one does not.

Comment: It is now the same

Comment: The problem is absolutely not that the list is being overwritten. The problem is that **`cString` and `nString` are `static`** and you're overwriting *those* each time you create a new `MainObject`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. And I hope you've learned not just about static vs. non-static (instance) fields, but also avoiding assumptions that lead to logical leaps, and how to provide a good example so that someone can give you the help you need.

Comment: I definitely have learned, and I really appreciate you sticking it out and helping me despite my logical leaps and incomplete information!

Comment: It was worth it in this case because you were receptive to the feedback.

Comment: @shu: I'm going to write an answer so you can accept it. Unlike other sites, putting the answer in the question is not how SO is intended to be used.

Comment: Will do. And honestly, you'd have to be awfully proud to ask for help and not listen to feedback so I do my best to pocket my ego when push comes to shove :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The definition of `MainClass` is using `static` fields and that's causing their values to be overwritten each time a new `MainObject` is created.

There's only one memory location for each `static` field.  In the constructor, that memory location is being assigned the value of the parameter, which overwrites any value previously passed to the constructor.

On the other hand, an *instance* (non-static) field has a separate location within each instance.  In that case, the assignment affects that object instance and not any others.

All you have to do is remove the `static` modifier from those properties.

```cs
class MainObject
{
    public MainObject() { }
    public MainObject(string theString) { nString = theString; cString = theString; }


    // Remove 'static' from these two declaration
    private string nString { get; set; }
    private string cString { get; set; }

    public string getString() { return nString; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is side effect of the way how you use WriteLine, or, to be more precise, where you use WriteLine. 
Modify your code to something like this:

```
List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
foreach (var theString in stringList)
{
    objects.Add(new Object(theString));
}

//this should be outside of first loop
foreach (Object object in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(object.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I've tried printing separately, as you have indicated, and all it gives me would be the 3rd object three times. I'm quite certain that it's overwriting all the entries in my List.